# Callback method shows error a value of type "void(*) cannot be used to initialize an entity of type

Tags: c++

I have a callback method. Its signature is

```
typedef unsigned int event_id_t;
typedef void(__stdcall* event_cb)(int service_id, event_id_t event_id);
```

And I defined a callback method as follows

```
void event_callback(int service_id, event_id_t event_id) {
    std::cout << _func_ << ": service_id: " << service_id << "; event_id: " << event_id << std::endl;
}
```

But I have an error when I assign the callback method to a variable

```
event_cb cb = event_callback;
```

This line gives error

> a value of type "void(*) (int serviceid....... cannot be used to
>   initialize an entity of type event_cb

Comment: Probably `__stdcall` mismatch

Comment: Definitely `__stdcall` mismatch.

Comment: I am not well versed with cpp Can you please elaborate a bit?

Comment: And how can I correct that?

Comment: Replace `void event_callback(int service_id, event_id_t event_id)` with `void __stdcall event_callback(int service_id, event_id_t event_id)`

Comment: remove `__stdcall` from `event_cb` or add it to `event_callback`

Comment: For (C-)callback, adding a `void* user_data` is useful to allow to pass state. Using `std::function` would be simpler though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking:

```
typedef void(__stdcall* event_cb)(int service_id, event_id_t event_id);
```

*and*

```
void event_callback(int service_id, event_id_t event_id) {
    std::cout << _func_ << ": service_id: " << service_id << "; event_id: " << event_id << std::endl;
}
```

is of different types (due to the calling convention) and hence the assignment fails.

To fix it, just add __stdcall on your side:

```
void __stdcall event_callback(int service_id, event_id_t event_id) {}
```